# Retrieve client side ddl.change() selecteditemtext and save in vb.net string

Tags: jquery, vb.net, string, events, client-side

This existing question "Filling a DropDownList with an AJAX response and getting the selected value on the server with ASP.NET WebForms" on stackoverflow came close to answering my question, but not quite.  I have a dropdownlist that is populated from a stored procedure that is called using jquery and a WebMethod.

After the dropdownlist is populated the selectedindexchanged event is handled client side and works beautifully, returning a string representing a date range (e.g. 01/01/2013 - 03/31/2012).  What I need to be able to do is capture the selecteditem text and save the string in vb so I can split it and pass the values of the date ranges individually to a vb.net function.

How can I get the selecteditem text that is changed client side and save it in a vb.net string variable??

```
accountingPeriodDDL.change(
                function (event) {
                    accountingPeriodSelection.val(accountingPeriodDDL.val());
                    accountingPeriodText.val($("option:selected", accountingPeriodDDL).text());
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store value in a Hidden Field. Values stored in hidden fields from client side are preserved during postback so you can read that value in server-side VB.NET code

Comment: Thank you, Yuriy.  I am needing to retrieve this value and have it available for a button_click event.  The value changes on the client side without a postback.  Are you saying that if I use a hidden field, then when I get to the button click event I can get the text value of the selected dropdownlist item from the hidden field in the button click event?  I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, if you modify hidden field's value in pure client code without postback and a while later do postback (e.g. button click) then server-side code will be able to read that value.

Comment: I am able to get the selected item text now whenever the selection is changed. This dropdownlist is populated by an Ajax call when the page initially loads. I need to access the selected item text of the dropdownlist after it loads via the Ajax call.  I tried checking out the value of my hidden field but it is empty because the dropdownlist isn't loaded in the Page_Load event of the Page.  Any suggestions on retrieving the initial selected value after the Ajax call that populates the dropdownlist?  Thanks.

Comment: Just execute on pageload the same code you execute on change event and this should give you initially selected value